# При попытке остановить springboot урлом /shutdown требует авторизацию

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

В application.properties добавлены поля

```
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true 
endpoints.shutdown.sensitive=false
```

Ожидается, что при вызове /shutdown произойдет корректное завершение приложения, но не могу вызвать этот урл,- ошибка не указан авторизейшн хэдер

```
curl -i -X POST someserver:7777/shutdown
```

Comment: Напишите подробнее об ошибке. Создный проект на start.spring.io с WEB+Actuator работает с данными конфигами.

Answer (score 0):

У вас очень мало кода spring-конфигурации приложения приведено, но попробуйте добавить эту строчку в **application.properties**:

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

Если используется spring security, то в вашей конфигурации WebSecurityConfiguration в методе configure необходимо добавить исключение в конфигурацию урлов, требующих авторизации.